# What are the units that measure free energy?

Tags: physical-chemistry, thermodynamics, free-energy, units

Is it $\pu{kJ/mol}$? I have done problems and I always end up with these units, but is this correct?

Answer (score 2):

In thermodynamics the change in free energy $\Delta G$ is given by,

$$\Delta G = \Delta H - T \Delta S$$

Hence by dimensional analysis, its units must be that of $\Delta$H, which is $\pu{kJ/mol}$.

It is logical because energy is usually measured in multiples of joules (SI Unit).

Answer (score 2):

> What are the units that measure free energy?

There are several different *free* energies, but I'll tackle Gibbs and Helmholtz only here:

1. **[Gibbs free energy](http://goldbook.iupac.org/html/G/G02629.html)**: $G=H-TS$, for $H=U+PV$. Hence, by dimensional analysis, Gibbs free energy has the SI units of Joule.
2. **[Helmholtz free energy](http://goldbook.iupac.org/html/H/H02772.html)**: $A=U-TS$. Again, by dimensional analysis, Helmholtz free energy also has the SI units of Joule.

Since both are only "free *energies*", it makes sense to assign them the SI unit Joule.

That said, however, almost everywhere they are specified in terms of $\pu{kJ/mol}$ because that makes the comparison across different substances easier. Since $G$ is an extensive function, its value can vary even with the amount of substance. Your calculated $\Delta G_\mathrm f^\circ$ can differ from mine even if we take the same substance, just because we had the amounts different. Hence, to ease comparison and computations, they are "specified" in terms of $\pu{kJ/mol}$, although their correct SI unit is Joule.