regarding units of $\Delta G$ = -nFE
Does the $\Delta G$ in this formula have units of energy/mol or simply energy (e.g., kcal or kJ)?
Is the number of electrons transferred "n" unitless?
My impression is that in this formula $\Delta G$ should be a molar energy and "n" should be unitless.
Please correct me if I'm wrong.
Thank you,
Al.

What keeps you from doing simple dimensional analysis? Energy/mol =   charge/mol times voltage.

I see no consistency in literature regarding this. Some books say that DG has units of energy, so "n" has units of moles, while others (more correct, I think) say that DG is a molar energy so "n" is unitless.

$\Delta_r G^\circ = -zFE^\circ$ as energy/mol. $\Delta G= -znFE$  as energy. If not given explicitly, then from context.

If you are consistent, $z$ is dimensionless and $n$ is an amount of substance with units of e.g. mol. Most introductory textbooks are not consistent, and most upper-level textbooks have typographical conventions to distinguish dimensions (molar or not, number or in moles).

Huh, it's a duplicate of a recent question, but I couldn't find it :/

Related: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/91240/72973
